# I have a strange issue occurring with Insight.Database mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, insight.database

I'm fairly new to C# and SQL Server, and I'm attempting to map some query results to an object with 3 layers of class hierarchy. I've made it work before, and it's actually working now, but not the way that I thought it would. Here, have some screenshots:

This works:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cjhe.png

This doesn't work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGZw1.png

Something that isn't clear from the screenshots is that the questions were mapping fine, it's the answers that weren't being assigned. It's a fairly small difference (and as I said it does work now), but I'd like to know if there's a way I can make Query.ReturnsSingle() map the answer children.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a bug with singles and multiple layers of objects. It should be fixed now.